# Simple form that hides after sumbmiting

Tags: javascript, html

As the title says. When you submit form dissapears for a second and after reload of the browser shows up again. CSS is a mess right I'm trying things out.

```
<div id="new_user_form" 
    style="
        width: 400px;
        height: 200px; 
        background-color: grey;">
    <form onsubmit="hide_show()" style="display: block;
    margin: 0 auto; 
        width: 100%;">
        New Nickname: <input type="text" required><br>
        New Password: <input type="password" required>
        <br><input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    function hide_show(){
        document.getElementById("new_user_form").style.display="none";

    }
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like you're on the right track. Did you have a specific question or problem with this code?

Comment: well it just shows up after posting the form

Comment: well... of course it shows when the page loads. Why wouldn't it? Pages do not magically remember what was showed before you loaded them. what is it you're trying to so?

Comment: well... it doesn't hide after submitting which is the problem that i'm trying to resolve

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit a form and after submit succeeds hide it from user without refreshing the page, then you should submit it through AJAX.

An informative example: https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery

Basically you submit the form through AJAX and when the request succeeds - you hide the form from user.